# Admin Products in Carts shows $0

Tags: magento2, admin

Magento 2.4.6 luma template. 2 Domain setting with single install .
Items added from second domain . Admin Products in Carts shows Item at $0 dollar.

Items in frontpage shopping cart and checkout is correct price .
[image]

any suggestion as to why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate on your question more? Please specify if you are adding products on the domain you set up and why items were added with the second domain.

Please specify the workflow with screenshots to reproduce your case.

Furthermore, please turn on the template Engine hints to identify the hints and also change the theme to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: Sites on local system . I have installed magento on domain1.com and everything works then I created new Website > Store > Store View for domain2.com
I configured Vhost of apache server and i can access both domain with no issue. 
as far as i can tell no issue in front end , i just see this $0 for domain2.com in admin > Reports > Products in Carts . I see correct price for Items that added using Domain1.com is jut odd .